# irreducibility of linear intersection?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $\operatorname{Gr}(k,n)$ be the grassmannian of $k$ planes in $\mathbb{C}^n$. Let $X$ be a fixed nonsingular algebraic variety in $\mathbb{C}^n$. Let $Z$ be the subset of $\operatorname{Gr}(k,n)$ consisting of $k$ planes intersecting $X$ with dimension at least one. If there exists a $k$ plane $L\in Z$ such that $L\cap X$ is irreducible. Can we say that for a generic element $L'$ in $Z$, $L'\cap X$ is irreducible? Thanks in advance!

Note: if $\dim(X)\ge n-k+1\ge 2$  then I think the statement is true since one can use Bertini's theorem.

Comment: What, precisely, do you mean by irreducible?  If $X$ is the affine cone over a quadric hypersurface, then every $2$-dimensional linear subspace $L$ of $\mathbb{C}^n$ intersects $X$.  For general $L$, the intersection is a union of two $1$-dimensional linear spaces intersecting at the origin.  But for special $L$, it may be a single $1$-dimensional linear space (thus irreducible), but with multiple structure.  Similar things can happen, even without multiplicity, if you allow that $L\cap X$ has higher dimension than $L'\cap X$.

Comment: @Jason Starr: By irreducible I meant the irreducibility of the underlying set. Thanks for your example!